# Changing playback control buttons tint color for AVPlayerViewController

Tags: ios, avplayer

I'm using a AVPlayerViewController, which by default provides playback controls. But is there a way to change the tint color of button images.[image]

For eg. I would like to change the play button and fullscreen button image tint color to white.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't customize the default media control of the AVPlayer.
What you can do is create an AVPlayerLayer with your own custom controls and interact with the AVPlayer.

There is a project called [Clappr](https://github.com/clappr/clappr-ios) with a custom media control that you can take a look to see how it works, and even change the UI as you want for your own project.